# Dynamically creating array of components

Tags: reactjs

I've followed this [tutorial](http://react.tips/how-to-create-components-dynamically-in-react-16/) but the requirement is a bit different. I've a function `getArrayList` that should generate an array of `ItemComponent`. The returned component will receive the items prop that is an array.

```
function getArrayList(ItemComponent) {
    return null // return a new component that renders an array of ItemComponent 
}

class Link extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <a href={ this.props.item.href }>{ this.props.item.text }</a>;
    }
}

const LinkList = getArrayList(Link);

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

if(LinkList) {
    let items = [
        { href:"https://www.yahoo.com", text:"Yahoo" },
        { href:"https://www.bing.com", text:"Bing" }
    ];
    ReactDOM.render(<LinkList items={items} />, rootElement);
    console.log(rootElement.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how to implement `getArrayList` that returns an array of components that will receive items (links) as an array and populate list of links, it's like a list wrapper module

Comment: a list wrapper that has `Link` array as it's children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
const getArrayList = (ItemComponent) => {
    const ListComponent = ({items}) => {
        return <div>{items.map(item => <ItemComponent item={item} />)}</div>
    }   
    return ListComponent
}
```

Comment: is `ListComponent` a React component? it has to be a component, it's the assignment requirement actually, it works though but somehow I've to meet the specs, I guess something like dynamic component? The component will receive `items` prop, like `this.props`

Comment: `ListComonent` is a [functional React component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const LinkList = (items) => (
    <div>
    {items.map(i => (
        <Link key={i.href} item={i}/> // pass the item as props ...
    ))}
    </div>
);
```

Note: react asks for `key` property when you dynamically create a list of components.